# java.net.UnknowHostException with ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap

I m doing my first steps with KSoap on Android (I m porting an iOS app to Android)

I get an exception while calling the WS

```
06-12 15:20:29.430: W/System.err(11912): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.mywebsite.com
```

I m pretty sure host is accessible and I get this error on a real android device with internet up.

Any ideas why?

Comment: did you add internet permission ?`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in your manifest file for Internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

if its not available then add it like this

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.samplesync"
    android:versionCode="yourversion code"
    android:versionName="your version name">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     .

     .
     .
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the INTERNET permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

OR

Your url doesnt have the host segment: should be like "http://www.mysite.com